# Toast Message In Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have A android project in Unity and I used SSTools for Toast message. So I Used This Code and Its work only for English Language(String = English words) I need to used it for Russian Words.
This Code Not work Properly.

```
switch(Application.systemLanguage)
            {
                case SystemLanguage.Russian:
                   SSTools.ShowMessage("Привет мир", SSTools.Position.bottom, SSTools.Time.twoSecond);
                    break;
                case SystemLanguage.English:
                   SSTools.ShowMessage("Hello World", SSTools.Position.bottom, SSTools.Time.twoSecond);
                    break;
            }
```

In System Language is English It work. But In Russian Language Message Not show But Toast Area show in interface.

Comment: try `SSTools.ShowMessage(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString("Привет мир"), SSTools.Position.bottom, SSTools.Time.twoSecond);`

Comment: Does't work..... :(

Comment: how to convert this code to Unicode??? (Best way)

Comment: You probably would need e.g. [`Encoding.Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.convert) or something similar

Comment: How to write Code that Encoding.Convert part according to my Coding.????

Answer (score 0):

There are no Any errors in my Code. Only thing is SSTools message Fonts is **NOT SUPPORT** to Russian Language. should be change the fonts in Unity SSTools.
my problem is Solve now. 
Thank you Everyone.